# Restart android app after SIGABRT / abort / Tgkill

Tags: android, android-ndk

My main goal is to restart the app when it crashed. I have used the Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler . But it isn't working with native crash like Tgkill. on https://testfairy.com/blog/ndk-crash-handling/ I have found some codes to implement that handler inside a cpp file. Currently I'm getting the logs of the crash generated by that nativeCrashHandler but don't know how to restart my app using that stuff. Currently I only know the Java/Kotlin. Any NDK / cpp experts please help to resolve this...